# Need a loop after a key input

Tags: c#, loops

Need to get it to loop after the user presses "r" at this part, need it to do as it says in the Console.WriteLine and redo all the questions

```
                if (numOfCorrect > 7)
                    Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("You got " + numOfCorrect + "correct! Incredible job! Can you do it again though? ");
                Console.WriteLine("If you want to retry the quiz press 'r', if you wish to exit the program press 'c'");

                if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.R)

                    Console.Clear();
```

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int iNum1;
        static int iNum2;
        static int numOfCorrect;
        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.WriteLine("Ten Question Multiplication Quiz");

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Instructions");
            Console.WriteLine("This program will give you 10 questions on multiplication for you to answer, after answering the ten questions it will display how many you got right!");
            Console.WriteLine("If you decide to retry the quiz it will have 10 completely different questions! So be prepared for a challenge.");
            Console.ResetColor();

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Start");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();

            Random rRandom = new Random();
            for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)
            {
                int userAnswer;
                int answer;


                iNum1 = rRandom.Next(11);
                iNum2 = rRandom.Next(11);
                
                {
                Console.Write("What is " + iNum1 + " times " + iNum2 + "? ");
                answer = iNum1 * iNum2;
                userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                if (answer == userAnswer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(userAnswer + " is correct ");
                    numOfCorrect++;
                    Console.Clear();

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(userAnswer + " is incorrect ");
                    Console.Clear();
                }

                if (userAnswer > 100)
                {
                    loop += (loop - 1);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("That number is too high, try again");
                }
            }
                {
                if (numOfCorrect > 7)
                    Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("You got " + numOfCorrect + "correct! Incredible job! Can you do it again though? ");
                Console.WriteLine("If you want to retry the quiz press 'r', if you wish to exit the program press 'c'");

                if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.R)

                    Console.Clear();



                
                else if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.C)
                    System.Environment.Exit(0);
                
                    
                }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put your code to the outer while(true) loop

Answer (score 0):

You can either capsulate your whole code inside another loop like pawel stated in his comment. Or you could also create a recursive function call like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

 Quiz();

}

void Quiz(){

 // Initialize stuff
 // Display stuff

 for(int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)
 {
  // Question User
  // Evaluate Answers
  // and so on

  // Check user input for retry
  if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.R)
  {
   Console.Clear();
   Quiz(); // <---- Calls the same method again
  }
 }
}
```